# Van Kampen theorem aplications

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm lost in how to use the Van Kampen Theorem, because I'm not sure how to proceed in this identification space.

[image]

Edit: I'm trying to follow this, but i do not see the link to do it.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know if they intend for the space that is being identified to be the whole plane, or the part of the plane between the two polygons, or only the two polygons (the lines)?

Comment: Reference of the pictures: A First Course in Algebraic Topology
By Czes Kosniowski